# Website doesn't display pages as requested until Control+F5

Tags: php

I have a strange situation here.

I had coded a webpage in php. It works fine throughout the day however if I close it down and try to access it again the following day it doesn't quite work as needed.

For example:
I have a main login page. When the user logs in the URL changes to the following page but it still shows the login input.

if i manually enter the URL again and press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>F5</kbd> I get the original page. If I then press on the logout page which calls the logout.php the URL does change but it still shows me the index page until I manually entere the URL and press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>F5</kbd> to force refresh.

once all the pages have been accessed this way the website they starts working fine again.

I have put headers to not cache the webpages but that is not helping here.

It happens with all browsers.

Any advice or am I sounding a bit stupid here?

```
header("Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate");
header("Expires: Mon, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT");
session_start();
if(isset ($_SESSION['user']))
{
echo "Logged in as:".$_SESSION['user'];
echo "<a href=\"index.php\">Home</a>";
echo "<a href=\"logout.php\">Logout</a>";
exit;   
}
else
{   
echo "<FORM name=\"login\" action=\"index.php\" method=\"POST\" onsubmit=\"return validatelogin(this);\">";
echo "<input type=\"text\" placeholder=\"Username\" name=\"username\">";
echo "<input type=\"password\" placeholder=\"Password\" name=\"password\"> ";
echo "<a href=\"forgot.php\">Forgot my password</a>";
echo "<input type=\"submit\" name=\"submit\" value=\"Submit\">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;";
echo "</FORM>";
```

Comment: close what down? the server?

Comment: Check if you are caching.

Comment: @Dagon: sorry i meant shut down my personal computer and try it again the next day.

Comment: @matzone: i have quite a few pages. I am happy to paste the code for my index page but it tells me its too long by 5700 characters..

Comment: i am pasting my login page instead. let me know if anything can help me solve my issue

Comment: @user2280769 - you should edit your question, and add the code in there